# Unable to initialise interface using BroadcastReceiver context in Android

Tags: java, android, interface, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver as below

***Test1.java***

```
public class Test1 extends BroadcastReceiver implements Test2.Interfacetest {

    private Test2 test2;

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       test2 = new Test2(context);
   }

   @Override
   public void interfaceTestMethod() {
        //code
   }

    /*
        Remaining code
    */

}
```

And have another class

***Test2.java***

```
public class Test2 {

    private Interfacetest InterfacetestCommander;

    public interface Interfacetest {
        void interfaceTestMethod();
    }

    public Test2(Context context) {
        InterfacetestCommander = (Interfacetest) context;

        InterfacetestCommander.interfaceTestMethod();
    }

    /*
        Remaining code
    */
}
```

When i try to initialise interface using broadcast receiver context, it gives following error

```
Process: in.ijasnahamed.interfaceTester, PID: 4452
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver in.ijasnahamed.interfaceTester.Test1: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to in.ijasnahamed.interfaceTester.Test2$interfaceTestMethod
```

**I need to know can an interface be initialized using broadcast receiver context? If yes, please tell me how?**

**N.B** : My real code is little bit longer. So i just showed revelant code here with some simple classes and method names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use

```
test2 = new Test2(context);
```

Because context is an instance of `Context`,but `Context` doesn't implement your interface,your Test1 class implement this interface,So you can add a parameter for your Test2 class like this:

```
public Test2(Context context, Interfacetest interfacetest) {
    this.mContext =  context;  //if you don't need the context,just ignore it 
    this.InterfacetestCommander = interfacetest
}
```

and change

```
test2 = new Test2(context);
```

to

```
test2 = new Test2(context,this);
```

Comment: Tried this. Error. Cannot use Test1.this instead of context. Does i need to change Test2 class constructor?

Comment: sorry,I forgot BroadcastReceiver is not subclass of Context.I think you can add a parameter which type is `Interfacetest` to your Test2 class constructor,when create it pass Test1.this to this parameter.

Comment: Did you mean to initialise interface like this  ' InterfacetestCommander = (Interfacetest) Test1.this; '

Comment: Since your Test1 class implements this interface,you needn't cast it to Interfacetest,please see my updated answer.